# Compiler Error involving QEventPrivate?

Tags: c++, qt

Hey so this code was working absolutely fine earlier today. Suddenly I started getting this really weird compiler error. Anywho, here's the header file:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

//Includes
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLayout>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    //Useful Functions
    void create_buttons                   ();
    void create_layout                    ();

    //Variables

    QPushButton* Button1                    ;
    QPushButton* Button2                    ;
    QPushButton* Button3                    ;
    QPushButton* Button4                    ;
    QHBoxLayout* ButtonContainer            ;
    QVBoxLayout* MainContainer              ;
    QWidget* MainWidget                     ;
}

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

And the cpp file:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
//    create_layout();
    create_buttons();

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
}


void MainWindow::create_buttons()
{
    Button1 = new QPushButton("Button1",this);
    Button2 = new QPushButton("Button2",this);
    Button3 = new QPushButton("Button3",this);
    Button4 = new QPushButton("Button4",this);

    ButtonContainer->addWidget(Button1);
    ButtonContainer->addWidget(Button2);
    ButtonContainer->addWidget(Button3);
    ButtonContainer->addWidget(Button4);
}


void MainWindow::create_layout()
{
    MainWidget = new QWidget;
    ButtonContainer = new QHBoxLayout;
    MainContainer = new QVBoxLayout;
    MainContainer->addLayout(ButtonContainer);
    MainWidget->setLayout(MainContainer);
    setCentralWidget(MainWidget);
}
```

Here's the compiler error: C2236: unexpected 'class' 'QEventPrivate'. Did you forget and a ';'?
I cannot for the life of me understand what's going on and if anyone can I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semi-colon at the end of your `MainWindow` class declaration

```
    QPushButton* Button4                    ;
    QHBoxLayout* ButtonContainer            ;
    QVBoxLayout* MainContainer              ;
    QWidget* MainWidget                     ;
}  // <- Missing semi-colon
```